# Why would 70-persistent-net.rules have no effect?

Tags: networking, 13.10, udev

I've got a saucy server with a lot of NICs and they end up with weird names like "rename19". I know interface names can be changed by modifying the /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules file. The first clue that something is wrong is that that file did not exist even though it's supposed to be created automatically. So I decided to write my own based on advice from Linux From Scratch:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", BUS=="pci", KERNELS=="0000:06:00.0", NAME="eth0"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", BUS=="pci", KERNELS=="0000:06:00.1", NAME="eth1"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", BUS=="pci", KERNELS=="0000:06:00.2", NAME="eth2"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", BUS=="pci", KERNELS=="0000:06:00.3", NAME="eth3"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", BUS=="pci", KERNELS=="0000:0c:00.0", NAME="mezz0"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", BUS=="pci", KERNELS=="0000:0c:00.1", NAME="mezz1"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", BUS=="pci", KERNELS=="0000:1b:00.0", NAME="slot1a"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", BUS=="pci", KERNELS=="0000:1b:00.1", NAME="slot1b"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", BUS=="pci", KERNELS=="0000:20:00.0", NAME="slot2a"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", BUS=="pci", KERNELS=="0000:20:00.1", NAME="slot2b"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", BUS=="pci", KERNELS=="0000:11:00.0", NAME="slot3a"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", BUS=="pci", KERNELS=="0000:11:00.1", NAME="slot3b"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", BUS=="pci", KERNELS=="0000:8b:00.0", NAME="slot4a"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", BUS=="pci", KERNELS=="0000:8b:00.1", NAME="slot4b"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", BUS=="pci", KERNELS=="0000:90:00.0", NAME="slot5a"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", BUS=="pci", KERNELS=="0000:90:00.1", NAME="slot5b"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", BUS=="pci", KERNELS=="0000:95:00.0", NAME="slot6a"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", BUS=="pci", KERNELS=="0000:95:00.1", NAME="slot6b"
```

(I'm matching on PCI IDs instead of MAC addresses because I have multiple identical machines that I want to apply this configuration to.)

After rebooting, nothing has changed. It's like these rules aren't even being read. There's not much going on in dmesg either:

```
$ dmesg | grep udev
[    3.196629] systemd-udevd[323]: starting version 204
[    6.719140] systemd-udevd[550]: starting version 204
[   38.695050] init: udev-fallback-graphics main process (1658) terminated with status 1
```

Comment: I found a similar question over in U&L: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46800/determining-nic-designation-from-pci-address/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently udev or kernel behavior changed sometime around 13.04 and now a different rule is needed:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNELS=="0000:06:00.0", NAME="eth0"
```

I debugged this using

```
udevadm info -a all -p /sys/class/net/em2
```

Comment: Thatnks for a `udevadm` command! Although on Debian Stretch I used `udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=/sys/class/net/eth0` to figure out the `KERNELS` value.